# mysql workbench total no of connections as tomcat says too many connections

Tags: mysql, tomcat7, mysql-workbench

Tomcat says too many connections error so i have increased the total no of connections but
in MySQL workbench as i am increasing the Connection Limit (set global max_connections) then the no of Total Connections also getting increases continuously.

i am started Connection Limit from 100 now reach to 5000 but the total connections getting over it.
as the tomcat console says too many connections and null pointer error so i am did that all
now help me out what to do in that scenario.

Comment: You're not closing connections to the db apparently, so no number you put there will ever work.  Recheck your code, and make 100% sure that you are actually properly closing db connections.

Comment: thanx fvu and all connections are in finally block all are closed..

Comment: Unless your application is actually serving 5000+ connections simultaneously and continuously, I highly doubt that connections are closed properly, otherwise you would not get this error, don't you agree?

Comment: Yes thats the only fact you are saying otherwise no problem is there ..

Comment: It should be apparent that there is a problem, otherwise the number of connections would remain low and more or less constant.  But without code we're not going to find that out, ever.  So, could you please add your code?

Comment: code is of thousands lines and hundreds of files so its is not possible to go through to code now fvk ...

Comment: is interactive_timeout and wait_timeout help in that scenario ?